# JiBX Eclipse Plugin not shown in Rational Application Developer 8

Tags: java, eclipse, jibx

I wanted to install the JiBX Eclipse Plugin in IBM Rational Application Developer 8.
The Installation works fine.
But after restarting the IDE there is nor context menu entry for JibX.

How do I add an entry for Jibx?

Answer (score 1):

veote,
Check in the 'plugin' directory of your Rational Application Developer installation to make sure the JiBX plugin is there.
It should be named:
org.jibx.eclipse_1.2.3.jar.
Sounds like there may be a slight difference between how RAD and eclipse handle plugins.
If it is not there, download our jar from here:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/eclipse/plugins/
and place it in the RAD 'dropins' directory.
Hope this helps
Don

Comment: the plugins directory is empty. so i put the jar file into the dropins directory, but this does not change the problem too.